# How to include .css file in .tsx typescript?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

How do i include "css" file in "tsx" and how to use it?
i.e how do i render static files?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Header } from "./header";

//import "./home.css";


export class Home extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="page-top" className="landing-page">
                <Header />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to make with the css file? in general it should be available if you included it before in HTML

Comment: it will work if i include css scripts in index.html bt i want to  use it in jsx in tsx file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot directly import CSS or any other static files into typescript using only the typescript compiler, but you can with the help of some build tools...

For example using [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/), you can set up the css-loader and style-loader to search your source code for `require('./whatever.css')` and add it to the build before safely compiling your typescript. If you also have webpack generate your HTML then your CSS will be automatically injected as a stylesheet.

Comment: but 'require' doesn't work in tsx , import './whatever.css'  works,

also how to do what you have mentioned in the last line

Comment: `import` should work, as long as you don't want to assign it to anything. If you do (ie if using CSS modules) then for the signature of `require` to not give you typescript warnings add the `@types/node` definitions to your project.

Without any of your build config it is hard to give precise instructions to achieve your goal - there are plenty of resources available to help get webpack set up if you haven't already. The loaders you need will need are [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader), and [typescript-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader)

Comment: hey thanx i added css-loader and file-loader(for images), it works, but how to serve js scripts to html automatically

Comment: Excellent. You can use the [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) to generate your html, which will automatically put any script and css link tags in there. If you have extra stuff currently that you still want to control you can pass it a template file...

`
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

/* in the webpack config object */
plugins: [ new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.template.ejs',
      inject: 'head'
    }) ]
`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358726/why-i-am-forced-to-write-es2015-while-converting-react-code-to-typescript

Comment: Here is a nice article with a css-loader replacement for typescript
https://medium.com/@sapegin/css-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack-6b221ebe5f10

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44283813) shows a simple way to copy CSS assets as part of a TypeScript build process.

Answer (score 12):

See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37144690/3850405

If you only need css for a class in your component you could do it like below. I like this solution for when inline css does not work and only small changes are needed.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Header } from "./header";

export class Home extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() {
        const css = `
        .landing-page {
            background-color: orange;
        }
        `
        return (
            <div>
                <style>
                    {css}
                </style>
                <div id="page-top" className="landing-page">
                    <Header />
                </div>
            </div>  
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer above

Comment: @xumix I don't understand your downvote. Your solution requires webpack and answers a question about typings - which the question is not about. I'm providing a link to a solution with webpack and giving an example without having to use a separate css-file.

Comment: The question is 1) about typescript, not js as your provided link 2) your answer is about adding inline styles but not including a css file into a tsx

Comment: Let's agree to disagree then. 
1) .Typescript yes since it is a `.tsx` file but the question is not about typings.
2) I still think my answer is a viable solution that does not require external dependencies. My link also provides an answer to including a .css-file - I do not like to duplicate another answer when it already exist.

Comment: "See my answer above – 
xumix
 Nov 22, 2017 at 10:00" it is now "below" here from users voting

Answer (score 8):

I've stumbled upon this question today also and found that TS now can import css directly with `webpack` and `awesome-typescript-loader` exactly like this:

```
import "./home.css";
```

But if you like me want to use CSS modules, than you will have to add some more steps:

1. `npm install --save-dev typings-for-css-modules-loader`
2. Change your `css-loader` to `typings-for-css-modules-loader`
3. Change your webpack config to smth like this:

```

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
        { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', "typings-for-css-modules-loader?namedExport&modules"] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader?minimize&namedExport&modules' }) },
        { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=1000' }
    ]
}
```

This will generate typings for css files and you will be able to use them like

```
import * as style from './home.css';
```

Here is the article I used for my config: https://medium.com/@sapegin/css-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack-6b221ebe5f10