# Cannot import CSS module in .tsx file

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, webpack, css-loader

I am building basic react application with typescript but I am not able to import CSS file in **index.tsx** file

I am able to import **index.css** file following way:

```
import './index.css'; 
//this import gives typescript error when running webpack
```

but not able to import as

```
import * as Styles from './index.css';
```

this is my **webpack.config.js** file

```
var path = require("path");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var config = {
    mode:"none",
    entry:"./src/index.tsx",
    output:{
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve:{
        extensions:[".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {test:/\.tsx?$/, loader:"awesome-typescript-loader"},
            { test: /\.css$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/'),
             loader:"typings-for-css-modules-loader" }
        ]
    },
    plugins:[new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './index.html'
    })]
};

module.exports = config;
```

I tried following links before posting but no luck

[How to include .css file in .tsx typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628247/how-to-include-css-file-in-tsx-typescript)

[How to import css file for into Component .jsx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143885/how-to-import-css-file-for-into-component-jsx-file/37144690#37144690)

https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/616

Thanks in advance

Comment: I edited code snippets ..sorry for wrong code

Comment: In my case, it's working fine, but giving tslint error 'Can not find module ./index.css '.
I tried from `https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx`

Comment: tslint search for files with extension `.ts` so might be in your case tslint is not able find `index.css.ts` file and because of this it's throwing error 'module not found'

Comment: my CSS file is with a `.css` extension not with `.css.ts`. like: index.css

Comment: TypeScript does not know that there are files other than `.ts` or `.tsx` so it will throw an error if an import has an unknown file suffix.

If you have a webpack config that allows you to import other types of files, you have to tell the TypeScript compiler that these files exist

Answer (score 2):

With the new version of React, to use CSS module you don't need to config anything in Webpack or reject your project.
All your need to do is:

1. Install `css-modules-loader`: https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules
2. Change the file name `styles.css` to `styles.module.css`
3. Import the css file to your component:

   `import styles from './styles.module.css'`
4. Use className in component:

   `<div className={styles.app}> Hello World </div>`

Demo project: https://codesandbox.io/s/kwyr5p378o

Comment: I tried above method but I am getting following error 

`You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> .foo {
|     color: chocolate;
|   }
 @ ./src/components/index.tsx 6:15-45`

after this I tried with css-loader and code is present in final **bundle.js** file but style is not getting applied to components

Comment: this method is working when I explicitly link CSS file in html

Comment: I am not using create-react-app template . I am building from scratch with no initial  configuration

Answer (score 0):

In `typings-for-css-modules-loader` [docs](https://github.com/Jimdo/typings-for-css-modules-loader#example-in-visual-studio-code), it's suggested that you import your `css` as

either

```
import styles from './index.css';
```

or

```
import * as styles from './index.css';
```

In your example, you are missing the keyword `from`